# R: For loop works on list, not individual element

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to learn by writing a function. It should convert the UOM (unit of measure) into a fraction of the standard UOM. In this case, 1/10 or 0.1

I'm trying to loop through a list generated from strsplit, but I only get the whole list, not each element in the list. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is strsplit the wrong function?  I don't think the problem is in strsplit, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the For loop:

```
qty<-0
convf<-0
uom <- "EA"
std <- "CA"
pack <-"1EA/10CA"

if(uom!=std){
    s<-strsplit(pack,split = '/')
        for (i in s){
            print(i)
            if(grep(uom,i)){
                qty<- regmatches(i,regexpr('[0-9]+',i))
            }
            if(grep(std,i)){
                convf<-regmatches(i, regexpr('[0-9]+',i))
            }
        } #end for
    qty<-as.numeric(qty)
    convf<-as.numeric(convf)
    }
return(qty/convf)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the ouput is a list = [1,1]

Answer (score 0):

maybe is a problem with the indexing of the list. Have you tried to use `[[1]]` after the `strsplit` function?

Example:

```
string <- "Hello/world"
mylist <- strsplit(string, "/")
## [[1]]
## [1] "Hello" "World"
```

But if we explicit say that we want the first "element" of the list with `[[1]]` we will have the entire array of the string.

Example:

```
string <- "Hello/World"
mylist <- strsplit(string, "/")[[1]]
## [1] "Hello" "World"
```

Hope this can help you in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.  The main problem you are having is that `s` is a list of length 1.  Within that list, the first (only) element is a vector of length 2.  Consequently, you would need to set `i in s[[1]]`.

However, we can go one step further.  Try the following code:

```
library(stringr) 
lapply(strsplit(pack,split = '/'),  # works within the list, can handle larger vectors for `pack`
  function(x, uom, std) {  
    reg_expr <- paste(uom,std, sep = "|") # call this on its own, it's just searching for the text saved in uom or std
    qty <- as.numeric(str_remove(x, reg_expr))  # removes that text and converts the string to a number
    names(qty) <- str_extract(x, reg_expr)  # extracts the text and uses it to name elements in qty

    qty[uom] / qty[std]  # your desired result.
  },
  uom = uom,  # since these are part of the function call, we need to specify what they are.  This is where you should change them.
  std = std)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're trying to practice, but I'd avoid loops while extracting the digits from a string like "1EA/10CA".  If it helps, the column `lst` is actually a list inside of a dataset.

```
library(magrittr)
ds      <- data.frame(pack = c("1EA/10CA", "1EA/4CA", "2EA/2CA"))
pattern <- "^(\\d+)EA/(\\d+)CA$"

ds %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    qty     = as.numeric(sub(pattern, "\\1", pack)),
    convf   = as.numeric(sub(pattern, "\\2", pack)),
    ratio   = qty / convf,
    lst     = purrr::map2(qty, convf, ~list(qty=.x[[1]], convf=.y[[1]]))
  )
```

Result:

```
      pack qty convf ratio   lst
1 1EA/10CA   1    10  0.10 1, 10
2  1EA/4CA   1     4  0.25  1, 4
3  2EA/2CA   2     2  1.00  2, 2
```